# How prove this inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\ln{i}}{i^4}<\frac{1}{14}$

Tags: inequality

I need to show that
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{\ln{i}}{i^4}<\dfrac{1}{14}$$

This problem from high school competition, so usage of integrals and infinite serries is forbidden.

My try: let $x\in (n-1,n)$,then
$$\dfrac{ln{x}}{x^4}<\dfrac{\ln{(n-1)}}{(n-1)^4}?$$
and then I can't proceed.

Thank you

Comment: Your problem involves an infinite series. It didn't make sense to rule out solution based on manipulation of infinite series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality under consideration is true for $n \le 6$: the Maple code $$evalf(seq(sum(ln(i)/i^4, i = 2 .. n)-1/14, n = 2 .. 6))  $$ produces $-0.28106872643574846732e-1, -0.14543757968659912271e-1, -0.9128545620535339541e-2, -0.6553444960640778942e-2, -0.5170914505989501935e-2 .$  For $n\ge 6$ the inequality $$ \sum_{i=2}^{i=n}\frac {\ln(i)}{i^4} \le \frac 1 {14}- \frac 1 2 \frac{\ln(n)} {n^3} $$ is true. This can be proved by induction.

1. The base of induction: up to Maple, $evalf(sum(ln(i)/i^4, i = 2 .. 6)) $  outputs $0.066257656922581926636 $ and $ evalf(1/14-(1/2)*ln(4)/6^3)$ produces $0.068219556703756866953. $

   2.Step of induction. It is enough  to prove the inequality $$ \frac 1 {14}-\frac 1 2 \frac{\ln(n)} {n^3} + \frac {\ln(n+1)}{(n+1)^4} \le \frac 1 {14}- \frac 1 2 \frac{\ln(n+1)} {(n+1)^3}\,\,(1)$$ for $n \ge 6$.
   This is equivalent to the inequality $$ \frac {\ln  \left( n+1 \right) }{ \left( n+1 \right) ^4}\leq \frac 1 2\,
   \frac {\ln  \left( n \right) }{n^3}-\frac 1 2\,\frac {\ln  \left( n+1
    \right) }{ \left( n+1 \right) ^3}=$$  $$ \frac 1 2\,\frac {\ln  \left( n \right) n^3-\ln  \left( n+1 \right) {n}
   ^{3}+3\,\ln  \left( n \right) {n}^{2}+3\,\ln  \left( n \right) n+\ln
    \left( n \right) }{n^3 \left( n+1 \right) ^3} \,\,(2).
    $$
   Making use of the inequality $ \ln(n+1) \le \ln(n) +\frac 1 n ,$ which follows from $\ln(1+x) \le x $ for $x > -1,$ we come to the inequality $$ \frac 1 2\,\frac {\ln  \left( n \right) n^3-\ln  \left( n+1 \right) {n}
   ^{3}+3\,\ln  \left( n \right) {n}^{2}+3\,\ln  \left( n \right) n+\ln
    \left( n \right) }{n^3 \left( n+1 \right) ^3} \ge $$ $$\frac 1 2 \,\frac {(3\,\ln \left( n \right) -1)n^2} {n^3 \left( n+1 \right) ^3} \ge  \frac 1 2 \frac {(3\,\ln \left( n \right) -1)}{n\left( n+1 \right) ^3}\ge \frac 1 2 \frac {\ln \left(\frac { n^3} e \right) }{(n+1)^4}. \,\,(3)$$ It remains to compare $\ln(n+1)$ with $\ln(\frac { n^3} e ) $ for $ n\ge 6.$It is clear that $ n^3/3 \ge n+1$ if $n \ge 6$. This can be established by using the derivative.

Answer (score 4):

Since 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\log x}{x}\right] = \frac{1 - \log x}{x^2} < 0
\quad\text{ when } x > e$$
We have 
$$\frac{\log k}{k} \le \frac{\log 4}{4} = \frac{\log 2}{2}\quad\text{ for any } k \ge 4.$$ As a result,
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\log k}{k^4}
= \sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac{\log k}{k}\right)\frac{1}{k^3}
\le \frac{\log 2}{2^4} + \frac{\log 3}{3^4} + \frac{\log 2}{2}\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3}
$$
Notice the last term is bounded by a telescoping series:
$$\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3} < \sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{k^3-k}
= \sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{1}{(k-1)k(k+1)}
= \frac12 \sum_{k=4}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{(k-1)k} - \frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)
= \frac12 \frac{1}{(4-1)4} = \frac{1}{24}
$$
We get
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\log k}{k^4} < \frac{\log 2}{16} + \frac{\log 3}{81} + \frac{\log 2}{48} = \frac{\log 2}{12} + \frac{\log 3}{81} \sim 0.071325 < \frac{1}{14}$$

Comment: Thank you,I hope see have without computer to help,because I don't can prove this $\dfrac{\ln{2}}{12}+\dfrac{\ln{3}}{81}\approx 0.071325$

Answer (score 1):

With the Riemann zeta function for $x>1$
$$\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$$ you get, taking the derivative term-wise 
$$\zeta'(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^x}.$$
Since all your terms are positive we have
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{\ln{i}}{i^4}
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\ln{i}}{i^4}
< -\zeta'(4) = 0.068911265896125379849\dots < \frac{1}{14}
$$

Comment: So why is $-\zeta'(4)= 0.068911265896125379849\dots$ ?

Comment: Thank you,This problem is  High school mathematics competition,so you can't use this integral and series methods.

Comment: @nanchangjian, then you MUST to note this in your question

Comment: Yes,@Norbert, I can note my question all time,Thank you